# removeStr.indexOf not removing all requested elements

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am still very much learning Javascript/Google Apps Script, but have created a javascript which takes certain google sheets relating to orders for a business, removes certain data not needed and then creates a list of the remaining ordered items by each item. This has all worked well for the first two of these google sheets, but when I come to the the third, I have an issue in that the `removeStr.indexOf` is not removing all the data I would expect it too and was therefore hoping someone could tell me where I am going wrong please?

[Here is an image of the raw data reduced to fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX6mn.jpg)

From the above the function firstly creates an array which produces the following

```
Status,NaN,Date Submitted,NaN,Name,NaN,Phone,NaN,Delivery Required?,NaN,Address ,NaN,GLATT SUMMARY,NaN,MH SUMMARY,NaN,GILBERTS SUMMARY,NaN,SMOKED SALMON SUMMARY,NaN,DOVIDS SUMMARY,NaN,Roaster,3,Wrapped Cut Up,1,Wrapped Cut Up Skinned,0,Carcus
,0,Half Hen,0,Mince,0,Lean Mince,2,Chicken Mince,0,Chicken Wings (8),0,Drumsticks (4),1,Thighs (4),0,Breasts (2),4,Pargiot (6),0,Hinds (2),0,Cumberland,2,Burger (4),0,Diced Steak,2,Fairy Steaks (Pack),1,Ribeye Steak,0,Bola,0,Lamb Chops (4),3,Shoulder Chops (2),0,Lamb Shanks (2),0,Shoulder Lamb (off bone),0,Shoulder Lamb (bone in),0,Turkey Thigh,0,Turkey Leg,0,Roaster Crown,0,Roaster in Tin,0,Meatballs 12,0,Meatballs Family,0,Lamb Shwarma,0,Thick Chops (4),0,Salmon 200g,1,Salmon 100g,2,Gefilte,0,Fishball (L),0,Fishball (S),0,ADDITIONAL ITEMS? (subject to availability),NaN
```

From the above array, the next stage is the to remove the unnecessary elements in two or so stages by firstly removing the not required strings via a removeStr.indexOf and then secondly by removing the NaN's linked to those remove strings. This is done as followed:-

```
// This array contains strings that needs to be removed from main array for Meat_Fish Order
var removeStr = ['Status' ,'Date Submitted' ,'Name' , 'Phone' , 'Delivery Required?' , 'Address ', 'GLATT SUMMARY' , 'MH SUMMARY' ,'GILBERTS SUMMARY' , 'SMOKED SALMON SUMMARY' , 'DOVIDS SUMMARY' , 'ADDITIONAL ITEMS? (subject to availability)'];
 
ordered = ordered.filter(function(val){
  return (removeStr.indexOf(val) == -1 ? true : false)
});

var ordered = ordered.filter(function(value) {
    return !Number.isNaN(value);
});
```

The above `removeStr.indexOf` is semi successfully, but for some reason is not removing Address, SMOKED SALMON SUMMARY and DOVIDS SUMMARY, as you can see below.

```
Address ,SMOKED SALMON SUMMARY,DOVIDS SUMMARY,Roaster,3,Wrapped Cut Up,1,Wrapped Cut Up Skinned,0,Carcus
,0,Half Hen,0,Mince,0,Lean Mince,2,Chicken Mince,0,Chicken Wings (8),0,Drumsticks (4),1,Thighs (4),0,Breasts (2),4,Pargiot (6),0,Hinds (2),0,Cumberland,2,Burger (4),0,Diced Steak,2,Fairy Steaks (Pack),1,Ribeye Steak,0,Bola,0,Lamb Chops (4),3,Shoulder Chops (2),0,Lamb Shanks (2),0,Shoulder Lamb (off bone),0,Shoulder Lamb (bone in),0,Turkey Thigh,0,Turkey Leg,0,Roaster Crown,0,Roaster in Tin,0,Meatballs 12,0,Meatballs Family,0,Lamb Shwarma,0,Thick Chops (4),0,Salmon 200g,1,Salmon 100g,2,Gefilte,0,Fishball (L),0,Fishball (S),0
```

I thought the issue was down possible to case, additional spacing, or something like that, but have matched exactly and still no joy.

As well as sorting this would be good to know if there is anything within Javascript which is of use to take away an potential issues with case sensitivity and additional spacing. Is there anything?

Big thanks in advance

Comment: You said you produced an array, but that's not an array. Show the actual array contents.

Comment: ordered is undefined

Answer (score 1):

to correct errors of whitespace and capital letters let's standardize all texts before:

```js
const standardize = val => {
  if (typeof val === 'string') return val.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase()

  return val
}

const standardizedRemoveStr = removeStr.map(standardize)

const res = ordered.filter(val => {
  return !standardizedRemoveStr.includes(standardize(val)) && !Number.isNaN(val)
})
```

Comment: Big thanks Marcelo, incorporating the replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase() into my code at an earlier stage has corrected the issue and solved the problem. Always great to get another persons eyes and experience on your work and once again a big, big thanks

Comment: It is always a pleasure to help. If we are not 100% sure of the string formating it's probably good to normalize the strings before compare them. If possible can mark as the correct answer?